# Get value from object array C# -> PHP

Tags: c#, php, arrays

Morning!

It's quite early in the morning, so I think the answer of my question will be obvious, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

This is the situation:
I have a C# application which communicaties via a WCF webservice with my PHP project.
Now, a function in my C# application generates something like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [GetSpecsResult] => stdClass Object ( 
[string] => Array (
 [0] => 
[1] => Test 
[2] => Test 
[3] => 14-8-2013 10:08:53 
[4] => 14-8-2013 10:08:52 
[5] => 
[6] => ) ) )
```

Basically, what I want is to get the values to print nicely in my PHP project.
I could do a foreach within a foreach, this works also, but I'm pretty sure that's not the correct way.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Goedemorgen! I assume you have multiple entries in that array, that you need a foreach?

Comment: Nothing wrong with two foreaches. Other than that I don't really get what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to print the values within the array into a table. That's why I was thinking of a double foreach, because basically it's an array into an array right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to do this is actually what you say, with a foreach on the array. You do not need a double foreach I think, because you likely only get one stdClass back for the 'GetSpecsResult'.

The clean nice/tidy way is to do this using an iterator on the array but that assumes you: a) have a object model and b) implemented the iterator.

Just go with one/two foreaches, it is the right thing to do!

Comment: Goedemorgen, This is what I use right now: 
foreach($specsresponse as $key=>$value){
foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1){
// table with values
}
}

But it just.. doesn't look right ;) It works though.

Comment: That is fine really. I am not sure about the full format of your result object, but you can probably use `foreach($specsresponse['GetSpecsResult'] as $key => $value)` - it saves you one foreach, which likely will only run once. Of course this assumes you will only get one SpecsResult, but normally C# works that way (with the wrapping)